# sha1 Hash Not working? C#

Tags: c#, security, sha1

I am just messing around with simple hashing because I am new to the idea, and I have the following:

```
public string Password {get;set;}
public static string Hash(string password)
    {
        return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "sha1");
    }

    public bool Authenticate(AccountDataContext context)
    {
        var password = context.UserAccounts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserAccountUID == UserAccountUID).Password;
        var hash = Hash(Password);
        return password.Equals(hash);
    }
```

**NOTE** This is not production code, so I am not worried about how secure this currently is...

Right now, when I originally hash the password when a user registers such as the following

```
var password = "Password";
var hashedPassword = UserAccount.Hash(password)
```

Then I am storing this with the user.

When I am authenticating my user I would call the Authenticate() method, and I thought it would  return the same hash, because it is passing the same value into the Hash() method, but they are coming out differently.

Any ideas why the Hash function would return two different hashes for the same string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completley sure in this case but usuall you don't only hash the password but the password and some additional random noise you save beside (often called salt-value).
This is done to make this all more secure than the password alone.
If you only store the pwd then an attacker could just hash dictionaries and find a lot *accepted* passwords.
I guess the same is happening here behind the scenes.

Have you considered Hashing the password yourself (System.Security) instead of using the FormAuthentication-Service?

Have a look at the [SHA1Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed.aspx).ComputeHash-method for this.
Basically you just encode your string with [UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.getbytes%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)- or whatever you want - into a byte-array and call this method to get a hashed byte-array. Than you can transform this with [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to get a string back - this is *WITHOUT* this salt I talked about so you might read into this before moving into production.

Answer (score 1):

The hashed result will be the same during multiple calls to the function. You might want to call String.Trim() prior to hashing to ensure there is no white space anywhere in the string prior to being hashed.

Also shouldn't the snippet you posted read:

```
public bool Authenticate(AccountDataContext context)
{
    var password = context.UserAccounts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserAccountUID == UserAccountUID).Password;
    var hash = Hash(password); //lower case password, not Password.
    return password.Equals(hash);
}
```